# Calculate Median If a range contains one of the values from another range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would  like to calculate Median of values in a column F, if the value in Column I contains one of the **NUMBERS** in a range (N5:N10).

Currently I am calculating using the following formula :

```
=MEDIAN(
      IF(
         OR(I4:I466 = N5, I4:I466 = N6,  I4:I466 = N7 ),
         F4:F466)
   )
```

Can anyone help me to replace the **OR statement** in the formula I am using ?

Thanks

Rahul

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

*You need to use an array (CSE) formula to compare two data range.*

- Formula in cell `E58`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(E$51:E$55,F$51:F$55)>0,0),MEDIAN(D51:D55),0),"")}
  ```

**N.B.** Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

- Cell `E57` has your formula:

  ```
  {=MEDIAN(IF(OR(E51:E55=F51,E51:E55=F52,E51:E55=F53,E51:E55=F54,E51:E55=F55),D51:D55,0))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- It must be an array (CSE) formula, and need to finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for such an illustrative example. You saved my day

Comment: Glad to help U @Rahul,,, since now the suggested method is useful to you then, [You may accept it as answer & vote too](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺

Comment: @Rajesh...I have voted but its not showing as my reputation is less than 15. Hope it will be shown soon. Thanks again for your efforts

Comment: @Rahul,, no issue but you may accept it as an `Answer`,, just click on grey tick mark on left top of my post,, will turn to green ! ☺

Comment: That's already done 

Comment: {=MEDIAN(IF(OR(E51:E55=F51,E51:E55=F52,E51:E55=F53,E51:E55=F54,E51:E55=F55),D51:D55,0))}